# overlayfs full inside docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

What does the below output mean and how to free it? I don't even know how is it used. Could not find much info. Any pointers are appreciated.
I am running this inside my docker container-`df -h.` command. This docker container is deployed from compose file on docker swarm cluster. I am on mac os and docker version is `17.06.1-ce`

```
bash-4.3$ df -h .
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  62.7G     59.5G     67.2M 100% /
bash-4.3$
```